# JQUERY Switch X div with a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Ive got X div with the class sort (and the sortable(); behavor)

```
<div class="sort" id="a"></div>
<div class="sort" id="b"></div>
<div class="sort" id="c"></div>
<div class="sort" id="d"></div>
<div class="sort" id="e"></div>
```

I want to switch their position onclick on a button

Ex to obtain that :

```
<div class="sort" id="b"></div>
<div class="sort" id="c"></div>
<div class="sort" id="e"></div>
<div class="sort" id="d"></div>
<div class="sort" id="a"></div>
```

Ive to do that :

```
$("#sort").sortable().disableSelection();
$("#sort li:eq(3)").insertAfter($("#sort li:eq(4)"));
$("#sort li:eq(0)").insertAfter($("#sort li:eq(4)"));
```

But i want to build a fonction to make this work with X elements, the function take an array as argument like that :

```
{'a' : 4 , 'b' : 0, 'c' : 1, 'e' : 2, 'd' : 3}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
function sortElements(ELEMENTS) {
    $("#sort").sortable().disableSelection();
    $.each(ELEMENTS, function (eleID, elePOS) {
        if ($('#' + eleID).index() != elePOS) {
            $("#" + eleID).insertAfter("#sort li:eq(" + elePOS + ")");
        }
    });
    //I assume you need to re-initialize the `sortable` widget here
}

$('#my-button').on('click', function () {
    sortElements({'a' : 4 , 'b' : 0, 'c' : 1, 'e' : 2, 'd' : 3});
    return false;
});
```

This passes in your object of element IDs and new positions and positions each element.

## Update

I added the `if` statement inside the `$.each()` loop that checks to see that the position to insert the element is the same position it currently has, which if you try to use `insertAfter()` to insert an element after itself, the element will just be removed from the DOM.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FMxZa/3/

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks, I just copied the original code without thinking about it.

Comment: @AntoninNivoche The problem was when you try to insert an element after itself it is just removed from the DOM. See the **update** to my answer for a fix, the demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/FMxZa/3/